# Python/Scilab bridge: scilab2py error

Tags: python, integration, scilab

I'm a newbie to Python but have experience in MATLAB/Scilab. I'm creating a mathematical model in Scilab, but the input data is generated from a Python (2.7) code. As a result, I'm trying to make use of the Python module scilab2py (see http://blink1073.github.io/scilab2py/source/installation.html) in order to run Scilab from inside Python to allow the process to be much simpler.

I installed all the required Python modules for scilab2py (i.e. Scipy, Numpy) and have Scilab installed in my PATH, so I installed scilab2py using

```
pip install scilab2py
```

which it says was successful. However, if I enter Python and try

```
import scilab2py
```

I am met with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import scilab2py
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scilab2py\__init__.py", line 46, in <module>
    lib1 = ctypes.CDLL(os.path.join(basepath, 'core', 'libmmd.dll'))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 366, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 126] The specified module could not be found
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error? Or perhaps know where I am going wrong with implementation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A hint is in `ctypes.CDLL(os.path.join(basepath, 'core', 'libmmd.dll'))` - it probably needs a library that provides `libmmd.dll`